# wxPython: selecting more rows in Grid does not work

Tags: python, wxpython

I have this code

```
     try:
        for rows in self.__allselectedrows:
            print self.myGrid.SelectRow(rows, True)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    print self.myGrid.GetSelectedRows()
```

in a EVT_GRID_RIGHT_CLICK in a wxPython Grid.
The Problem:
after the loop(yeah, I have checked, the loop will be executed and it goes into the `SelectRow` function) the output of `GetSelectedRows()` = [] empty list... Why this happen?

Comment: What is the output of `print self.myGrid.SelectRow(rows, True)`

Comment: `None`, but I think there is no other opinion?